# Need to run ksh script in windows korn shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I am new to korn shell, I am trying to run ksh script that to kill all 3 days older process in my server, that works good for direct input, but when I put this in a for look script I got error, someone please help.
FYI, korn shell is installed in windows server.

```
> cat test.ksh
#! /usr/bin/ksh

for i in {ps -eo etime,pid,args | awk -F- '$1>3{print}' | grep -i read_ini | awk '{print $2}'}
do
kill -9 $i
done

LCQU@SETOPLCORA01Q [/dev/fs/E/home/serora]
> ./test.ksh
./test.ksh[3]: syntax error: `|' unexpected
LCQU@SETOPLCORA01Q [/dev/fs/E/home/serora]

> ksh test.ksh
test.ksh[3]: syntax error: `|' unexpected
LCQU@SETOPLCORA01Q [/dev/fs/E/home/serora]

> ls -l test.ksh
-rwxrwx---  1 jagadee  Domain Users  133 Dec 24 13:16 test.ksh
```

Comment: The result can be empty. So you can get such errors. But before try again think about `init` process!!! And BTW in Windows you will miss a lot of programs like `ps`, `awk`, `grep`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `{}` but `$()` for a subprocess:

```
for i in $(ps -eo etime,pid,args | awk -F- '$1>3{print}' | grep -i read_ini | awk '{print $2}')
do
   kill -9 $i
done
```